# I've merged a branch, but not all changes have merged?

Tags: git

I've merged a branch into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge work_branch
```

There were some conflicts which I resolved and committed, however there are some changes which didn't come across and I can't figure out why.

If I do `git checkout work_branch` I can see that the file `views.py` is different from `master`, but if I do `git merge work_branch` from `master` I get `Already up-to-date.` What's going on here? I want `master` to be identical to `work_branch`.

Comment: Have you run `git revert` on anything in master?  For instance, did you intentionally/inadvertently merge `work_branch` to `master` and then `git revert` this merge?

Comment: @AndrewMyers Yes I did, I accidentally merged and reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have, after your merge

```
A -- B -- C -- F
 \            /L master
  \- D -- E--/
          L work_branch
```

If your commit `B` changes `views.py`, and if you didn't change it on `work_branch`, then it's normal that

- You don't have a conflict on that file while merging
- The file won't be the same on both branches (ie: between commits `E` and `F`)
- There's no point in merging `work_branch` again, hence the `Already up-to-date`.

If you want `master` to be exactly like `work_branch` (ie: like commit `E`), you could do, at the root of your repo

```
git checkout master
git checkout work_branch -- .
git commit --all
```

---

Edit to follow-up on comment:

On the other hand, if you only changed `views.py` in commit `E` (ie: neither on `B` nor on `C`), then it seems quite strange that the file isn't the same on `E` and `F`.

If you didn't push / share your merge commit, you might want to retry the merge, in case an manipulation error occurred previously:

```
git checkout C
git branch -f master
git checkout master
git merge work_branch
```

Comment: My problem is that work in commit E hasn't merged over to master, i.e. several commits from `work_branch` haven't merged.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not familiar with the Git workflow.

You may have not committed in your `work_branch`. Make sure that you have committed your work in `work_bench`.

When you have resolved the conflicts, make sure that you did `git add views.py` before `git commit` or simply `git commit` with `-a` option (I always forget to do this)

If you assist that you did everything right, I think I need to know the log of your repo to see what has happened indeed.

Answer (score 0):

`git merge` performs a *three-way merge* between the branch you're on and the branch you merge in. What this means is that, roughly, git:

1. Identifies a common ancestor commit; the "nearest" commit that's shared by both `master` and `work_branch`;
2. Generates a diff between that ancestor and `master`, and a diff between that ancestor and `work_branch`. These diffs describe the work that was done on each branch.
3. Applies each diff from `work_branch` that doesn't conflict with one on `master`.

So, merging in a branch doesn't make the branch you're on *identical* to the one you merge in, it gives you a new state that has *all of the work from both sides*.

If what you actually want to do really is make one branch identical to another, you can (while you have `master` checked out):

1. Use `git checkout work_branch -- .` in the top-level directory to make your working copy exactly the state it is in `work_branch`, and commit those changes. (You can also do this for individual paths or directories). This will create a new commit in `master`'s existing history that introduces changes to make it identical. Or:
2. Use `git reset --hard work_branch` while you're in `master`. This replaces `master`'s history with `work_branch`'s.

Comment: I have a feeling this has happened because I thought I knew what I was doing with `rebase` but didn't...

Comment: Ah, that could be; usually when this happens it's because the branch topography is different than you think it is. You can use `git log -p master ^work_branch` and `git log -p work_branch ^master` to see the commits and patches on each side that are getting merged, or `git log --oneline --decorate --graph master work_branch` to see the branches' relationship in ASCII art.

Comment: Due to `rebase` my work branch was up to date with commits from master, so I used @gturri's tip to just overwrite everything, thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you noted that you had previously `git reverted` I think you're running afoul of the interaction between merge and revert.  `git revert` works by creating a new commit which exactly undoes the reverted commit.  So for instance say you have the following tree.

```
A  -- master
|  B  -- work_branch
|  |
| /
M  -- Merge work_branch to master.
|
C -- New commit on master.
|
M'  -- git revert M (undoes B)
```

In this scenario you merge `work_branch` into `master`, then commit something new to `master` on top of the merge and then decide you that `work_branch` is not ready for `master` yet. You now have a couple options to fix this.

- `git reset --hard` back to commit `A` and then `git cherry-pick C` back into `master`.
- `git rebase -i` back to A and delete commit `M`
- `git revert M` which creates commit `M'`

The first two options are basically equivalent they just have different work flows.  The last option leaves you with both `M` and a new commit `M'` in your history where `M'` contains changes that exactly undo *everything brought in during the merge that created `M`*.

The problem arises when you decide `work_branch` is now ready and you want to merge it.  When you do the merge *you will not get any changes from `work_branch` which occurred in `M` and were undone by `M'`*.  In order to get the changes back you have to remove the effect of commit `M'` on your history.  You have again a couple options, they are essentially the same but now you're trying to remove `M'`.

The simplest thing to do will most likely be to revert the revert commit.  So `git revert M'`  prior to merging `work_branch` again.  This will also work after remerging `work_branch` but it may cause conflicts you would not get when doing it before.  This will get you to something like:

```
A  -- master
|  B  -- work_branch
|  |
| /|
M  |     -- Merge work_branch to master.
|  |
C  |    -- New commit on master.
|  |
M' D     -- git revert M (undoes B) 
| /
F        -- git merge work_branch (You see changes from D, but not B)
|
M''   -- git revert M' (undoes M', you now see changes from B)
```